# jQuery Mobile input not styled coming from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a pretty basic jquery mobile page, it's 3 `data-role:page` divs in one `index.php`.  The first page is simply a background image and an `input type="tel"` with `position:fixed` in the center of the screen.  If I load the site directly on the iPhone the style and positioning are all correct.

However, people will reach the site through an external link that passes in a parameter (e.g. `?event=123123123`, a random string).  When loading this way, the first page ALWAYS loads un-styled, i.e. the input box is ignoring all css, both the jquery.css and my own, whether it's inline, declared in the head, loaded from an external file, etc.  If I refresh the page, then the style kicks in and it looks like it's supposed to.

I've tried basically everything I can think of (and lots of things that probably don't even make sense) like binding to `pagebeforeload`, `pageinit`, `pageshow` etc. like for example:

```
$( '#step1' ).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
 // alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );

 $('<div id="formbox"><form><input type="tel" name="number" id="number" value="" style="width:87%; height:40px; font-size:36px; font-weight: bold; left:14px; position:relative; text-align:center;" /></form></div>').appendTo('#formboxouter');
 // var $container = $('#step1');
 // refreshStyles($container);
 $('#formbox').trigger('create');
 // $( window.document ).trigger( "mobileinit" );
});
```

I've reached the 'throw everything at the wall and see what sticks' phase of frustration and, well, nothing has stuck.

I've found lots of info about ways to modify internal links (e.g. `rel=external`) but I've found nothing that seems to explain why this could happen.

Why is it that passing an external parameter would cause the styles not to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read the documentation for JQM regarding parameters. Also try `$('.ui-page').trigger('create');` instead of `$('#formbox').trigger('create');`

> **Passing parameters between pages**
>
> jQuery Mobile does not support query
> parameter passing to internal/embedded pages. For example, if the
> framework sees a link to "#somePage?someId=1" it interpret that as
> "#somePage" and navigate to the internal page div with an ID of
> somePage and apply a data-url of #somePage?someId=1 to that page
> container. Subsequent calls to other params such as
> "#somePage?someId=2" will find the same div because jQuery Mobile
> refers to the data-url on the div which is only set once and will
> remain at #somePage?someId=1.
>
> There are two plugins that you can add to your project if query
> parameters are needed between pages. There is a lightweight [page
> params plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router)
> for use with backbone.js or spine.js.

[info source](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I fooled with that a bit, but in the end the problem was actually set wrongly to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">`. When changed to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` the scaling issue was solved.  I think the page was trying to render at 320px instead of the 640 the iphone 4s uses, which caused the box to falsely render until a refresh.